# englishing topology (munkres)

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through Munkres' Topology.

2.16.1 asks "Show that if Y is a subspace of X, and A is a subset of Y, then the topology A inherits as a subspace of Y is the same as the topology it inherits as a subspace of X".

I'm a little autistic and as Topology is a new kind of math for me, I'm a bit confused what this question is trying to ask. I keep re-reading it, and to me the english is so off that I can't understand. If I had a little bit more of a background in the subject, I think that I might be able to figure out what it is trying to ask, but...

Comment: is it meant to say "Let Y be a subspace of X, and A $\subset$ Y. Prove that the topology (T,A) = the topology (T, X)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to expand on the situation, and let you take it from there.

In the problem, $X$ is a topological space (say with topology $\tau_X$), and $A, Y$ are two subsets of $X$. As such, both $A$ and $Y$ can be equipped with the subspace topology inhereted from $X$ (let's call these $\tau_{A, X}$ and $\tau_{Y,X}$, respectively).

In addition, it is given that $A \subset Y$, and so viewing $(Y, \tau_{Y, X})$ as a topological space, we can also equip $A$ with the subspace topology inhereted from $Y$, say $\tau_{A, Y}$. The question then asks you to show that $\tau_{A, Y} = \tau_{A, X}$.

Comment: ty. sorry if dumb question.